# How to fix Ionic (ios) page navigation issues?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3

I am Currently experiencing experiencing navigation issues in the iOS version of the application. When navigating, the page drops to the bottom right of the screen - show a black background - then navigates to a new page.

![Image of the transition issue] https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIZcy.jpg

Currently, I have not been able to find a solution to this issues. I have tried changing the transition of the ionic pages but it just compounds issues

this.navCtrl.push(PollsPage);

```
       this.navCtrl.push(PollsPage, {}, {
          direction: 'back', // default for push is 'forward'
          duration: 2000, // 2 seconds
          easing: 'ease-out'
      }
```

Ideally, I'd like the pages to transition like the Android version of the application where the pages transition/navigate without a the screen dropping to the bottom right first.

Comment: are you using  the custom ionic icon?

Comment: No I am not but I do not think the icons affect how navigation occurs.

Comment: I have same issue but due to custom icon

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me , but the **prperty** is "**animated**" and I am using **Ionic V4**

```
IonicModule.forRoot({ scrollPadding: "false", scrollAssist: false, **animated:false** })
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, all you need to do is: 
1) Go to app.module.ts
2) change 'IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)' to 'IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {animate:false})'

Answer (score 1):

- It worked for me , but the prperty is "animated" and I am using Ionic V4

  IonicModule.forRoot({
    scrollPadding: "false",
    scrollAssist: false,
    animated:false
  }),